# react component not rendering on my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I installed react-rails on my project, added the

```
gem 'react-rails'
```

then I used

```
rails g react:install
```

I have my index html index.html.erb with the react_component helper calling my componnet

```
<%= react_component("Post", {title: "Hello World"}) %>
```

And I have this post component at app/assets/javascript/components/post.jsx

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>    
  }
}
```

But my component is not rendering on the screen

why?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have added the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` directive into your layout file.

Also in my case I forgot to run `rails generate react:install` as specified here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#3-now-run-the-installers which sets up the ReactRailsUJS setup in app/javascript/packs/application.js

Answer (score 9):

Just need to add prerender: true, in the component, and it works.

```
<%= react_component("Post", {title: "Hello World"}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

Comment: I've had the same problem, and this fixed it for me, too. Do you know why it needs to be added?

Comment: Heads'up: When adding `prerender` you are saying that the component will be rendered on the server side. If you are importing any dependency that is not listed on the `server_rendering.js` it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Running this line again.

```
rails webpacker:install:react
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the return portion in your render function requires parenthesis:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<h1>{this.props.title}</h1>)
   }
}
```